# Allow_Remove doesn't remove the collection

Tags: php, collections, zend-framework2

I'm setting a fieldset (collection) in my form, and i want allow add and remove elements.. So, my code is:

```
    $hydrator = new Hydrator($this->getObjectManager(), 'Base\Entity\MyElements');

        $fieldset = new MyElements();

        $fieldset->setObjectManager($this->getObjectManager())
                 ->setHydrator($hydrator)
                 ->setObject(new \Base\Entity\MyElements())
                 ->init();       

 $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
            'name' => 'myElements',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'My Elements',
                'count' => 1,
                 'should_create_template' => true,
                 'allow_add' => true,
                 'allow_remove' => true,
                'target_element' => $fieldset
            )
        ));
```

I can add elements, but, the remove button doesn't appear.. I'm doing wrong or forgetting something?

PS: My english is very poor, but i'm trying improve it. Sorry. And thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The allow_remove option doesnt add the button directly. Remeber that the allow_add also does not add the button. As you can see in [the docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html#adding-new-elements-dynamically) you have to add the button

```
<button onclick="return add_category()">Add a new category</button>
```

and the js function to add elements:

```
<script>
    function add_category() {
        var currentCount = $('form > fieldset > fieldset').length;
        var template = $('form > fieldset > span').data('template');
        template = template.replace(/__index__/g, currentCount);

        $('form > fieldset').append(template);

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

exactly as this, you have to add the remove button

```
<button onclick="return remove_category()">Remove</button>
```

and the function:

```
<script>
    function remove_category() {
       //write your logic to remove the last, or the current element, for isntance:

         $('form > fieldset > fieldset').last().remove();
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I realized now that this is not automatic! In my project, which is huge, someone implemented the allow_add method, but the allow_remove isn't done yet! Thank you man!

Comment: Yeah! much people has the add function since it is available in the zf2 docs, but the other one is not!. :) please accept the answer so it can be useful to other users!